# Antd-mobile is giving warning: "You are using a whole package of antd-mobile"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, antd, antd-mobile

I followed the instructions in [antd-mobile usage link](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-mobile/blob/HEAD/docs/react/introduce.en-US.md#%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85) for importing antd-mobile using babel-plugin-import, however when I use an import of the format:

```
import {Card as CardMobile, WhiteSpace} from 'antd-mobile';
```

This warning still appears in the browser console log:

```
You are using a whole package of antd-mobile, please use https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel- 
plugin-import to reduce app bundle size.
```

I can resolve the warning by using manual import references:

```
import WhiteSpace from 'antd-mobile/lib/white-space';
import 'antd-mobile/lib/white-space/style/css';
import CardMobile from 'antd-mobile/lib/card';
import 'antd-mobile/lib/card/style/css';
```

but I was hoping to use the less verbose, non-manual form.

Here's the plugin configuration settings in .babelrc:

```
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/transform-runtime",
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "libraryDirectory": "lib"}, "antd"],
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd-mobile", "libraryDirectory": "lib"}, "antd-mobile"],
    ["babel-plugin-webpack-alias", { "config": "./webpack.config.common.js" }]
  ],
```

Here are some of the package versions from package.json (let me know if any other package versions are needed):

```
"antd-mobile": "2.3.4",
"babel-plugin-import": "1.11.2",
"@babel/core": "7.2.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Card as CardMobile, WhiteSpace} from 'antd-mobile';
```

here you are accessing the whole package. we need to split it down.

```
import Card as CardMobile from 'antd-mobile/Card';
import WhiteSpace from 'antd-mobile/WhiteSpace';
```

now we are importing only the specific things, what we will be using in our file.

Comment: The antd-mobile instructions indicate this should work:  
import { DatePicker } from 'antd-mobile';   
What you provided looks almost identical to the manual format I used as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

[Use modularized antd-mobile](https://mobile.ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app#Use-modularized-antd-mobile) From antd-mobile site metioned [How does it work?](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand)

Go to the [target page](https://ant.design/docs/react/getting-started#Import-on-Demand), you will see (sorry for I can't post image directly for now):

[snapshot, click to check out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1bJ6.png)

> you might still be using `webpack@1.x` or have a wrong webpack config which can't support tree shaking.